How to play audio in sequence in the reverse mode?
I’ve added audio to sequence and it works fine, but when I play it in the reverse mode, audio doesn’t play. I don’t need it to play in reverse too, to play it the opposite order - audio 2 and then audio 1. How can I do it?

I can do it like this with blueprint, but if I enter the trigger - animation with audio plays and in the middle of it I exit the trigger - it stops and play in reverse mode. Then if I enter trigger again while animation plays in the reverse mode - it will play in normal mode again and main thing - audio plays from that point, where we on the timeline right now.
And I can’t do it with the blueprint below. There should be a way to do it because it looks like a basic thing.

